# Double patenting and continuation patents that don't continue

Tags: us20150339333

Microsoft do seem to like double patenting, even though they have to make terminal disclaimers in respect of their applications. But I cannot see the point, unless it's just to increase the cost of ex-parte attempts to invalidate their patents.

They're also submitting continuing applications that do not contain additional claims for the invention in the patent being continued, but instead contain claims that duplicate, more or less, those in a different patent. They seem to be getting away with that, which I'd have thought they shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here. Would you be able to clarify it?

Comment: Well, is there a point to double patenting? Am I right that contination patents shouldn't contain claims that don't relate to the invention of the parent patent?

Comment: You might be best placed to separate those into two different questions, as double patenting is not really related to continuations. The latter question may actually be quite an interesting point. Also, the questions you noted in your comments should probably be edited into the question itself (since comments may disappear later).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this is done to patent different aspects of an invention. Ideally, the claims will not overlap, but may sound very similar and basically all prevent the usage of the actual invention.

This increases the cost of defending against infringement suits and taking down the patents **dramatically**.

There are other strategical reasons, for example it is possible to first get a fast grant on a narrow version of the claims to get some protection and with that in the backhand seeking wider protection through many years of correspondence with the patent office.

I have actually seen the double patenting regulation be used against such claims, so I'm confident that the claims from Micrsoft don't overlap as much as you indicate in the question, but it might be hard to see the differences without thorough analysis.